# Difficulty sourcing websites from worksheet then returning results

Tags: excel, selenium

I am trying to write a script to scrape data from a set of websites that I have listed in a worksheet.  I would like to return the scraped data to a separate worksheet. What I have not yet been able to figure out how to do is get my script to read the first worksheet entry, return the data, then read the second, return the data etc. This is what I have written so far (as you can see, I just have a sample of the first website that I am scraping).

```
Option Explicit
Private cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub WeeklyPrices()

Dim cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer
Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

cd.AddArgument "--headless"

cd.start
cd.get "https://www.hamsmarketing.ca/market_data/January-4-2021/"

'Find Header

Dim H2Headers As Selenium.WebElements
Dim H2Header As Selenium.WebElement

Set H2Headers = cd.FindElementsByCss("h2:nth-of-type(4)")

For Each H2Header In H2Headers

Worksheets.Add
Range("A2").Value = H2Header.Text

RowNum = 1
ColNum = 1
Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = H2Header.Text
'ColNum = ColNum + 1
'RowNum = RowNum + 1
Next H2Header

'H2Header.AsSelect.ToExcel Worksheets.Add.Range("A1")

' Find Prices

Dim OtdListItems As Selenium.WebElements
Dim OtdListItem As Selenium.WebElement

Set OtdListItems = cd.FindElementsByCss("ul:nth-of-type(4)")

For Each OtdListItem In OtdListItems
Range("B2").Value = OtdListItem.Text

    Next OtdListItem

cd.Quit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I tried this and I can get it to go to a sheet and print output, but, it just prints the last returned values in all of the cells :-(

Option Explicit
Private cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver

Sub WeeklyPrices()

```
' Open Chrome

Dim cd As Selenium.ChromeDriver
Dim RowNum As Integer, ColNum As Integer
Set cd = New Selenium.ChromeDriver

Dim Count As Integer
For Count = 1 To 2

Dim Value As String
Dim names As Range
Set names = Range("c1:c2")
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In names

cd.AddArgument "--headless"

cd.start
cd.get cell.Value

'Find Headers

Dim H2Headers As Selenium.WebElements
Dim H2Header As Selenium.WebElement

Set H2Headers = cd.FindElementsByCss("h2:nth-of-type(4)")

For Each H2Header In H2Headers

'Debug.Print H2Header.Text

RowNum = Count
ColNum = 1
Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = H2Header.Text

Next H2Header

' Find Prices

Dim OtdListItems As Selenium.WebElements
Dim OtdListItem As Selenium.WebElement

Set OtdListItems = cd.FindElementsByCss("ul:nth-of-type(4)")

For Each OtdListItem In OtdListItems

'Debug.Print OtdListItem.Text

RowNum = Count
ColNum = 2
Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = OtdListItem.Text

Next OtdListItem

Next cell

Next Count

cd.Quit

End Sub
```